# About conversion operator and operator()

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, operator-overloading

In the following code:

```
template <class T> class mval {
protected:
    T max;
public:
    template <class iter> mval (iter begin, iter end):max(*begin) {
        while(begin != end) {
            (*this)(*begin);
            ++begin;
        }
    }
    void operator()(const T &t) {
        if (t > max)
            max = t;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << max;
    }
};

int main() {
    int arr[3] = { 10,20,5 };
    (mval<int>(arr, arr + 3)).print();
}
```

Why does `(*this)(*begin);` leads to the `operator()`?

Shouldn't it go to this operator only when you have something like `mval x; x(T);` ? But it behaves like it's a conversion operator, how?

Comment: `(*this)` results in an reference to an `mval`, which you can then call `operator()` on. This is the same reason `x(T)` works, `x` is an `mval`.

Comment: On a side note, your code has a logical bug - you derefence `begin` - but what if you are provided with a zero-sized container?

Comment: @SergeyA it's not my code, it's from a test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is `mval x; x(T);` any different than `(*this)(*begin);`? In both cases I see an object of type `mval` followed by parentheses with one argument inside. What did you expect to happen? `(*this)` is not a type, it's an lvalue of type `mval`, so I don't see how it "behaves like it's a conversion operator" either.

Comment: `(*this)(*begin);` looks like casting to mval: `(mval)(*begin)`

Comment: @kuhaku: As I said in my answer, `*this` is ***not*** a type

Comment: @kuhaku, `this` is not a type. `*this` is not a type. So there is no casting operator anywhere in sight.